# SQL - dúvida em consulta

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, query, oracle

Tenho a seguinte consulta pra fazer, consegui pensar nelas de forma separada. Estou começando a estudar banco de dados e não sei como relacionar as duas.

> Tabela Ocorrencia
> numero, data, descricao, cpfprofissionalseg

> Tabela Ocorrenciapessoa
> {cpfpessoa, numeroocorrencia}

> Tabela Espectador
> {cpfpessoa, codigo}

> Tabela Pessoa
> {cpf, datanascimento, nome, tipopessoa }

"Para cada espectador, selecione CPF, nome, código e, se foi envolvido em alguma ocorrência, inclua data (sem a hora) e a descrição da ocorrência."

```
SELECT p.cpf, p.nome, e.codigo 
FROM pessoa p, espectador e 
INNER JOIN p ON e.cpfpessoa = p.cpf

SELECT o.data, o.descricao 
FROM ocorrencia o, ocorrenciapessoa op
```

Answer (score 0):

Sua sintaxe para junção está errada.
Tente:

```
SELECT p.cpf, p.nome, e.codigo, o.data, o.descricao 
FROM pessoa p 
INNER JOIN espectador e ON e.cpfpessoa = p.cpf
INNER JOIN Ocorrenciapessoa op ON e.cpfpessoa = e.cpfpessoa
INNER JOIN ocorrencia o ON o.numero = op.numeroocorrencia
```

Você não informou o formato do campo data para especifica-la "sem a hora".

Comment: TO_DATE('1987/01/12 00:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') Esse é o formato

Comment: Então não especifique hora, minuto e segundo.